# Submit Button Not working After an Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Submit button does not work after an ajax call; however, if I load the page it works fine. This is what is going on: I do have a modal that shows a dialog concerning email change confirmation. If the user clicks confirm, then the form submits fine; however, if the user clicks no and go ahead and submits the form with the originally saved email address, but updates different forms, the button does not submits anything. I would have to reload the page again to make it work. Here is the JS code for the above behavior.

==> In a nutshell, what I am trying to do is as follows: If the customer comes and tries to change their email address, the modal pops up with a confirmation message (Yes or no). If they click yes then the form submits fine; however, if they click no and reenter their original email, the submit button does not submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('confirmEmailChange').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('updateCustomerInfoFormId').submit();
      return false;
    };
    $('#updateInfoBut').click(function() {

      let currentCustomerEmail = $('#currentCustomerEmail').val();
      let customerEmail = $('#customerEmail').val();

      if (currentCustomerEmail !== customerEmail) {

        $('form[name=update_customer]').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: "This is our API URL" + customerEmail,
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(json) {

          },
          statusCode: {
            404: function() {
              $('#customerInfoModal').modal({
                show: true
              });

            },
            200: function() {
              $('#emailAlreadyUsedModal').modal({
                show: true
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console log for errors ?  It's possible an error has been encountered, which is preventing the button from working.

Comment: @devlincarnate I do not get any errors in the console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out by moving the `e.preventDefault();` inside the if statement function, and manually submitting the button outside the ajax call when the modal is confirmed. The following works great:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  document.getElementById('confirmEmailChange').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('updateCustomerInfoFormId').submit();
      return false;
  };

  $('#updateInfoBut').on('click', function(e) {
    let currentCustomerEmail = $('#currentCustomerEmail').val();
    let customerEmail = $('#customerEmail').val();
        if(currentCustomerEmail !== customerEmail){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
               url:"API LINK GOES HERE" + customerEmail,
               dataType: 'text',
               success:function(json){
               },
               statusCode: {
               404: function() {
                 $('#customerInfoModal').modal({show: true});

               },
               200: function() {
                 $('#emailAlreadyUsedModal').modal({show: true});

               }
                }
          });

        } 
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

```
$('form[name=update_customer]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

is preventing the form from submit itself via `preventDefault()` call.

The default action of a form submit is to submit the form itself, by prevent the default action you basically tells the form to submit then stop it from submitting.

If you look at [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler), you will find that passing a callback to submit() essentially gives it a handler rather than submit the form. And the handler will be called every time when you try to submit the form in other ways.

Comment: Yes, I need that behavior to check for other validations. I later on submit the form through other button clicks...

Comment: @Zeusox : HOW do you submit the form "through other button clicks"?  Please update your question with that code segment.

Comment: @Zeusox Because when you intercept the submit function, you are not only trigger this one but also adding the callback to the form submit. If you add a line of log before the `preventDefault()` call, you should see it get triggered everytime you are trying to submit the form, either via button click or other methods.

Comment: @Zeusox - Putting `e.preventDefault()` there makes that part of the code pointless. As @Chen says your form is never sent.

Comment: @EternalHour, Thank you! What would be a better alternative!

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to send the form via ajax, leave the preventDefault and move your ajax call inside the submit event.

Comment: @EternalHour I am actually submitting the form through a function that checks if the click is on the button is "yes". WIth that being said, if I change email input then hit submit, I get a modal on which if I click yes, the form submits fine. But if I click no and try to resubmit the form is stuck and does not go anywhere!

Comment: @Zeusox May be you can validate the form manually instead of calling the submit?